# Nativescript radiobutton

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am developing a NativeScript application. I want to use radiobutton functionality in my application.

I have tried to achieve this by using "nativescript-radiobutton" plugin, but it doesn't support in iOS.

Is there any solution through which it works for both Android and iOS platform?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can use nativescript-checkbox https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Html for the radio button -

```
<Label text="{{ checkYes ? '&#xf192;' : '&#xf10c;'}}" 
       class="{{ checkYes ? 'fontawesome' : 'radioBefore'}}" 
       (tap)="changeAction()">
</Label>
```

Apply these two classes for Font Awesome -

```
.font-awesome {
   font-family: "fontawesome-webfont";
   font-size: 24;
}

.radioBefore {
   font-family: "fontawesome-webfont";
   font-size: 24;
}
```

Add Font-awesome.ttf file in fonts folder and then change the radio buttons *selected* or *unselected* with `changeAction()`

Function - Initialize 
`this.changeYes = true`

```
 changeGenderMale(){
    if(this.changeYes == true)
      this.changeYes = false;
    else
      this.changeYes = true;
 }
```